# DOMPDF: how to concatenate more DOMPDF outputs

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm working around the DOMPDF issue limit about the tables that exceed the page length.

I have a loop and for each step I ask DOMPDF to render one page with a subrange of rows that can stay altogether into the page.

No errors, but when I send the output to the screen (or create the output PDF file) I only see the last step of the loop, with the last subrange of rows...

Here my code:

```
...
$output = '';
$initrow = 0;
$rowsperpage = 25;
$items_nr = 100; //total nr of rows

while ($initrow < $items_nr) 
{   

    // instantiate and use the dompdf class
    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('enable_html5_parser', true);
    $options->set('isJavascriptEnabled', true);

    $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

    ob_start();

    $_GET['initrow'] = $initrow;
    $_GET['rowsperpage'] = $rowsperpage;

    //get the html from my php page                 
    require "./mypage.php"; 
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    
    //Create PDF
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', "$x_orientation");

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    $output = $output . $dompdf->output(); 
    
    $initrow = $initrow + $rowsperpage;     
    
}   

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream($output, array("Attachment" => false));
exit(0);
...
```

some idea?
thanks to everyone

Comment: You render in the loop , so it's last element that stay in output. Try to set your render out of the while scope, to see what will happen.

Comment: Hi @Romylussone, great suggestion" tried to move the render just outside the while but I get the error **"Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent"**. Guess because this way I create something with more **<body></body>** inside...  What I would need, perhaps, is to concatenate the PDF contents altogether ...

Comment: yes try to use concat option  approach, i think it'll be better. also you should remove your dompdf options and all dompdf stuffs from your while loop after that, concat you html content in while loop, then  you'll load properly your html content in your dompdf element outside the while. hoping that you'll get me.

Comment: getting errors on html concatenate...it seems harder than I thought...

Comment: GREAT!!!!! DID IT!!! excellent suggestion Romylussone! a bit trouble in appending childs but at the end we did it!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Ok cool, nice job...